# Rails 3: Filtering and scopes "cant convert hash to integer" problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a "course" model, which has_many timeslots.

In the courses model, I have the following  methods:

```
def available_timeslots
  tsarray = []
  self.timeslots.map{ |t|
    if t.available then
      tsarray << t
    end
  }
  tsarray
end

def earliest_slot
  self.available_timeslots.first(:order => :starting_date)
end
```

What I'm trying to do now is get the earliest available timeslot for each course.  Without the availability filter, @course.earliest_slot works fine. But if I try @course.available_timeslots.earliest_slot brings back a "can't convert hash into integer" message.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Untested Thought: It looks like the `:order => :starting_date` is a hash being passed to the `first` method of `Array`. `first` [takes an optional integer argument](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000222) (e.g. "return me first 20 elements"). Try removing that argument to the `first` method. Maybe the types of objects being returned in the two separate calls are different (proxy?) and that is why you're seeing the error on the call which is using a simple `Array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zabba's comment is right on the money.  The available_timeslots method is returning an Array and you are calling the method first on that -- but that is not the same as calling the method first on the object that a Rails association returns.

I think you want to use scopes.  So delete your available_timeslots method and add this to your Timeslot class:

```
scope :available, where(:available => true)
```

then in your earliest_slot method you can do

```
self.timeslots.available.first(:order => :starting_date)
```

and it will return the first available timeslot for the course referred to by 'self'.

(Note: I am making the assumption that 'available' is a boolean.  If it is something else, change the where condition in the scope appropriately.)

Comment: I agree with using scopes, but for the finder, why not:

    self.timeslots.available.order('starting_date').first

I think in Rails 3, using #order is preferred to passed it in as an argument. At least it seems that way from the guides.